# Android Studio Error : button more than one time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Error: Found item String/button more than one time Android Studio
 Ican't solve this problem can any one help me 
this error in Android studio SDK 
About Buttons

Comment: Check if you have same Button id's in same view.

Answer (score 0):

Go to open string.xml in valuse in Res
clear it
and write this :-

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Caluclator</string>
    <string name="button">Button</string>
</resources>
```